# J2ME applications in Nokia 2660

Tags: java-me, nokia, midlet

It's possible to install J2ME Midlets in the Nokia 2660 cellphone? The installation of the Midlet is via bluetooth or physical cable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If testing for a app that'll be available for public download you should test OTA (Over The Air). This way you'll be testing it in the same way your users will be using it.

OTA basically means put-it-on-a-server-for-download. You'll need a server setup with the correct MIME types; but that's a different question.

Comment: Depends what you are testing for if it is just application functionality then the install method makes no difference? Once you have confirmed that your install process works it is often easier to debug/test via bluetooth/cable. just my 2 cents. Developers having to use OTA to debug would make me far less productive!!

Answer (score 0):

[Yes it is!](http://stats.getjar.com/device/Nokia/2600_classic)  Bluetooth, cable or over the air.